# intellij scala create executable jar file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, executable-jar

H everybody! I'm trying to create an executable jar file from a scala project in Intellij. At the moment my artifact looks like this:
[image] and the artifact builds fine. When I try to run the artifact on the command line however I get:

```
[edouard@localhost datagenerator_jar]$ java jar datagenerator.jar
Erreur : impossible de trouver ou charger la classe principale jar
```

(Error : cannot find or load main class jar)

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? As far as I know, the Main Class is defined correctly (It is the one suggested for my project by the Intellij plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually issued a wrong launch command.

You should do

```
java -jar datagenerator.jar
```

Without "jar" being an option (with "-"), a main class named "jar" were searched (and not found).